# New JSSignatureProvider is not a function in EOSJS

Tags: eosjs

Version of EOSJS
`eos@fffff and eos@beta3`

Describe the bug

```
const JsSignatureProvider = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
const signature = new JsSignatureProvider([privKey]);
```

> TypeError: JsSignatureProvider is not a constructor

Steps to reproduce the behavior:
try and follow the first 6 lines of the documentation for getting started

Expected behavior: works

Desktop (please complete the following information): Ubuntu 16.04. node 8.14.0

Smartphone (please complete the following information):
no

Answer (score 0):

try .default at the end of the sig providor module

```
const JsSignatureProvider = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig').default;  // development only


const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } = require('eosjs');
const JsSignatureProvider = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig').default;  // development only
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('util');
```

Example use

```
exports.transferToken = function(paramss, context) {
  console.log((paramss.amount).toPrecision(5))
  const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([context.privKey]);
  let rpc = new JsonRpc("http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80", { fetch });
  const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });
  async function tx() {
    try {
      let resp = await api.transact({ actions: [{
          account: paramss.contract,
          name: 'transfer',
          authorization: [{
            actor: paramss.sender,
            permission: 'active',
          }],
          data: {
            from: paramss.sender,
            to: paramss.receiver,
            quantity: `${(paramss.amount).toFixed(4)} ${paramss.symbol}`,
            memo: paramss.memo,
          },
        }]
      }, {
        blocksBehind: 3,
        expireSeconds: 30,
      });
      resp = {...resp, paramss}
      console.log(resp);
        return resp
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return err
    }
  }
  tx()
}
```

Comment: nodude that didn't work.... what version

Comment: eosjs@20.0.0-beta3

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same error try using this import statement I hope it'll work

```
const { JsSignatureProvider } = require('eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig');
```